# awk issue inside for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk

I have many files with different names that end with `txt`.

```
rtfgtq56.txt
fgutr567.txt
..
```

So I am running this command

```
for i in *txt
do
  awk -F "\t" '{print $2}' $i | grep "K" | awk '{print}' ORS=';' | awk -F "\t" '{OFS="\t"; print $i, $1}' > ${i%.txt*}.k
done
```

My problem is that I want to add the name of every file in the first column, so I run this part:

```
awk -F "\t" '{OFS="\t"; print $i, $1}' > ${i%.txt*}
```

`$i` means the file that are in the for loop,
but it did not work because awk can't read the `$i` in the for loop.
Do you know how I can solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Comment: Could you please [edit] to clarify what the xpected output should look like? You want the filename, a tab, and all the values from the second column from lines which contain `K` in a single column with semicolons between them?

Comment: Using the `-v` option of `awk`, you can create an awk Variable based on a shell variable. See the awk man-page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `-v` option of `awk`, you can create an awk Variable based on a shell variable.

```
awk -v i="$i" ....
```

Another possibility would be to make `i` an environment variable, which means that awk can access it via the predefined `ENVIRON` array, i.e. as `ENVIRON["i"]`.

Answer (score 3):

You want to refactor eveything into a single Awk script anyway, and take care to [quote your shell variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

```
for i in *.txt
do
    awk -F "\t" '/K/{a = a ";" $2}
      END { print FILENAME, substr(a, 1) }' "$i" > "${i%.txt*}.k"
done
```

... assuming I untangled your logic correctly. The `FILENAME` Awk variable contains the current input file name.

More generally, if you genuinely want to pass a variable from a shell script to Awk, you can use

```
awk -v awkvar="$shellvar" ' .... # your awk script here
    # Use awkwar to refer to the Awk variable'
```

Perhaps see also [useless use of `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep).

Comment: ... and you don't need the variable anyway because you don't need the loop, you could do the whole thing in 1 call to awk. But that'd be a different question.

Comment: Yeah, but then you'd need to write to the output file from Awk instead, which I didn't want to tackle in what's obviously a beginner question.

Comment: Understood, hence `But that'd be a different question`, just figured the OP should be made aware.